# How is the additional damage computed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

So there are a number of skills that have a description like "Skill A does x dmg, some other effects. Skill A does y% additional dmg".

For example: Warden bear

> Rouse a loyal grizzly to fight at your side. The grizzly's swipe deals
>   Magic Damage. Once summoned, you can activate Guardian's Wrath for 75
>   Ultimate. Causes Magic Damage and deals 100% additional damage to
>   targets under 25% Health. The grizzly's attacks do an additional 12%
>   damage. Player's Note: while switching weapons bear disappears unless
>   slotted on both ultimate slots

There are other skills with description like that (all sorcs pets, overload, etc.)

Now, y% from what? I'm assuming is not from its own damage because then they could've just increased the tooltip.